Handling unreliable async operations of a 3rd party library
Say there is a 3rd party library that is out of our control.
Say that library has a number of methods with either signature:
Task SomeMethod()

Task SomeOtherMethod(CancellationToken ct)

Now say this library cannot be trusted to function correctly.
Say these awaited calls may never return due to whatever malfunction.
How might one wrap these to handle such a situation?
One thing that I believe has been suggested was to call these in a new thread, but I'm not completely sure of how to do this best.
While at the same time it was suggested that this wasn't even adequate as while the thread could be aborted, the awaited call itself might stay alive.
Honestly I'm confused.
I'd love to see some examples of these calls wrapped so I might begin to understand what can be done.

If logic does not support cancellation, you can't cancel it. But you always can cancel await of those non trustworthy methods. For that purpose .NET6 introduced Task.WaitAsync, with a couple of overloads (CancellationToken/Timespan parameters). Be aware if those methods takes too long time to finish execution and modify some shared state that can lead to unpredictable results.

What are you going to do when you discover this library hangs?  Just keep running as though nothing happened and still have a functional program?  Then save yourself the trouble and assume it failed at startup.  Don't use it.

@HansPassant sure, thought lets say that the library is a work in progress that moves rather slowly, and there are no alternatives currently.  For example the library has at least one documented case where its is in turn calling into the OS and the OS is failing to respond on occasion.  Some companies move real slow....

@Ryan This is one point i am confused.  And additional info might be relevant information i should have added: The library is in turn calling into the OS and from what we know so far the OS has issues/bugs causing the malfunction.  In that case isn't it true appending WaitAsync to the call may cancel the call into the library, but doesn't necessarily cancel any nested async calls into the OS that the library is making?

@axa, WaitAsync doesn't cancel any code, that does not support cancellation natively on its own. It is only used for control flow, when we want to ensure that execution falls into specfied timespan (ie we have strict timeouts for that execution). Regarding unexpected shared state - i will show you code sample.


Now say this library cannot be trusted to function correctly.

If a library cannot be trusted to function correctly, the application that uses this library cannot be trusted to function correctly either. So ideally you would prefer to avoid this library, and search for a trustworthy one.
The safest thing that you can do is to invoke this library on a separate process, and either:

Kill the process if the library takes too long to respond.
After the library responds, either kill the process anyway or keep it alive for the next invocation.

This way any corruptive effect of this library will not affect the state of the main process of your application. Depending on what the library does, it might still corrupt state that is external to your main process, like files or databases. Theoretically a malicious library could even fight back and kill your own process.
The APIs that you would need to implement this scheme are the Process class, the Kill method, and some form of inter-process communication so that you can pass the arguments of the invocation and receive the result.

I understand your methodology, and while library certainly has issues that must be addressed, in this case i would like apply a band aid until the issue can be resolved.
Fwiw, so far while profiling we find it leaking memory, the failing call doesn't put the application in a critical state as the application has a limited life span.
So I like to avoid Killing the process, rather find a work around it until repaired.

@axa sure, in a situation like this you have to pick your poison, and each situation is different. You have more information about which poison is less painful than anyone else here.

When its a memory leak then the aren't many poisons available that even slightly work. And without specific details about the nature of that leak the only safe solution is putting it in its own process like proposed by you.

Regarding Task.WaitAsync - you can use this for control flow unless tasks internally do modify some shared state. This is some rough imitation of shared state being changed that causes unpredictable outcomes.
var state = new TrafficLight();
Console.WriteLine($"Initial state: {state}");

try
{
    await state.MakeLongRunningTransitionTo(TrafficLightColor.Green).WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Traffic light failed changing state for specified period - rolling back to safe state: {TrafficLightColor.Red}");
    //safety transition
    state.MakeFastTransitionTo(TrafficLightColor.Red);
    Console.WriteLine($"Fast transition state: {state}");
}


//imitate some other long-running operation
await Task.Delay(3000);
Console.WriteLine($"Final state: {state}"); //BANG!! Potentially dangerous GREEN state on the road - RED is expected


class TrafficLight
{
    public TrafficLightColor CurrentColor { get; set; } = TrafficLightColor.Yellow;

    public async Task MakeLongRunningTransitionTo(TrafficLightColor toColor)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        CurrentColor = toColor;
    }

    public void MakeFastTransitionTo(TrafficLightColor color) => CurrentColor = color;

    public override string ToString() => CurrentColor.ToString();
}

enum TrafficLightColor
{
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green
}

Usually it is okay to use with http requests, cause of they do not touch some shared state - we only play with control flow to ensure our program load data fast or fail fast.

To put it another way, the WaitAsync cancels the waiting of the asynchronous operation, not the asynchronous operation itself. Using the WaitAsync with the intention of fire-and-forgetting asynchronous operations is an act of desperation IMHO. Personally I would prefer to walk on nails than to lose track of my tasks and let them become fire-and-forget (unless it's for an unimportant project that I don't really care about).

Yep, i agree that there are cases where this trick is absolutely unacceptable. From the other hand, before SDK6 i had at least twice in two different projects to implement WithTimeout() task extension, and now we have this feature built-in in BCL - good to know the SDK is getting more and more polished.
